# How to use Delphi's built-in multilingual support?

Tags: delphi, multilingual

I use Delphi since version 2 and now on the version XE3.

Since `BSD2006` I've noticed this menu `Languages` on the `Project` main **menu**. Now that I am interested in build an application available in *English, Portuguese* and *Spanish*, I searched for tutorials on the Internet but couldn't find anything about this function, only third party components and wizards. Since English is not my first language, I don't even know how to look for the right terms in order to get to this Delphi tool.

Does anyone already used this tool? Where Can I find a proper tutorial to get started? Thanks.

[image]

**Edit1: Response**

Since Remy answered correctly, but with a link, I will resume it so other can get to it quickly:

1. Save all your project files
2. Go to Menu > Project > Languages > Add
3. Add as many languages as you need
4. Go to Menu > View > Project Manager
5. You will see your project plus a project for each language you created
6. Expand one language project and you will see the `DFM` files to translate your forms
7. Right click and open one and you will see the *Translation Editor*
8. Translate all the needed strings and then save the file
9. Again in the *Project manager* expand .\Win32\Debug\ and see the `RC` resource files
10. Right click one and edit the constant strings of all the units files of your app

More Tips:

- In order to get the strings of your own units into the translation list file, you have to create them as constants, but using not the `consts` reserved word, but the `resourcestring` one, like: `resourcestring Str1 = 'Test'; StrN = '%s strings found';`
- Every time you create a new `resourcestring` or add a visual component on a form, you have to update the languages metadata, and to do it, go to Menu > Project > Languages > Update Localized Projects
- Every time you finish to translate the terms on your language files, you not just have to save those files, but you have to re-build the projects they belong. It's easier if you go to Menu > Project > Build All Projects

*These tips are not explained in the Embarcadero Help. Thanks Remy!*

Comment: Can you please summarize for us how usable is that tool? If I want to translate tomorrow my app, should I jump head first and start using that tool? There are any drawbacks? There are better alternatives? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by reading the documentation:

[Localizing Applications by Using Translation Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Localizing_Applications_by_Using_Translation_Manager_Overview)

[Adding Languages to a Project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Adding_Languages_to_a_Project)

Comment: or just add C-3PO to your Uses clause