# How to set manually TDateTimePicker language?

Tags: delphi, multilingual, vcl, delphi-xe7

I prepare a multilanguage application and I need to set up (from code) a month names in `TDateTimePicker`?

I know that this is dependent on the operating system version, but maybe another way?

Comment: What is `DateTimePicker`? Can you be precise about Delphi version and the control to which you refer and which framework you use?

Comment: Standard `TDateTimePicker` from `Win32` category. Delphi XE7

Comment: How are you handling the multilingual aspects in the rest of your program?

Comment: I have global function. This fuction get a form name, and set up a caption on components (Buttons,Labels,RadioButtons itp.) from `TDictionary` in `ComponentCount` - depent loop. Thing like hints etc. I translate mannually (on `FormShow `I set up translating fuction for caption).

Comment: I don't think `TDateTimePicker` is going to submit to that. If you program was properly multilingual then the system would do it for you. I'd advise you to reconsider your approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Delphi's built-in multilingual support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954958/how-to-use-delphis-built-in-multilingual-support)

Comment: You're implementing your multi-language support incorrectly. If you do it properly, Windows will handle the month names for you, and TDateTimePicker will automatically use them. If you implement it wrong, you're fighting the OS the entire way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to change the language for TDateTimePicker yourself. Why?

TDateTimePicker is just a wrapper for Windows common control that allows picking of time and date and therefore is dependent on windows language settings.

Also if you run your application with TDateTimePicker on different versions of Windows you will notice that it even looks differently

Date Time Picker on Windows XP
[image: Date Time Picker on Windows XP]

Date Time Picker on Windows 7
[image: Date Time Picker on Windows 7]

Date Time Picker on Windows 10
[image: Date Time Picker on Windows 10]

Notice that while on Windows XP and Windows 7 TDateTimePicker is fully shown in Slovenian (my default OS language) on Windows 10 it fails to show all texts in it in Slovenian.